# Change IE Document mode with Ajax response header?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

One question may not be valid or I have an answer but, is there a way to change browser document mode with Ajax success response from server? Basically server will add browser compatibility in response header based on segments of URL query string.

My suspect here is, it may not possible as this way security become weak but better to get expert opinion. :)

Answer (score 1):

The browser compatibility mode (quirks mode, etc.) is based on the main HTML document, namely the doctype. Since an AJAX request can do nothing to alter this, no, you cannot change the mode dynamically via an AJAX request.

However, quirks mode is a *fallback*. It's not something you *design* for. You should not be relying on specific browser compatibility features.